# How to split email body text in logic app

Tags: json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have following email body (paragraph) in a string in logic app. I want add a new line after "Hello Customer," and also the text "Best Regards, in a separate line and then "Support Team" should go to next line.

> Hello Customer, Thanks for reaching out to us. We appreciate your
> interest in our business. This is to confirm that we’ve successfully
> received your request.If you need immediate assistance or have any
> further questions, feel free to call us at phone.Best Regards, Support
> Team

I'm expecting the email body in the following format. How can I achieve this in logic app.

> Hello Customer,
>
> Thanks for reaching out to us. We appreciate your interest in our
> business. This is to confirm that we’ve successfully received your
> request you need immediate assistance or have any further questions,
> feel free to call us at phone.
>
> Best Regards, Support Team

Comment: you have said that you need, support team in another line, you can get it next line you just need to type the way you want in mail and use <pre>, you will get that way you just need to write in next line in Compose and then close </pre>, thats it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it using HTML, something like this ...

[image: HTML]

... the exact example above is untested but it should give you an idea.

Comment: @RithwikBojja  Thank you. "Support Team" text should go to next line. That means  "Best Regards" in one line and "Support Team"  should be in another line.

Comment: You commented on the wrong answer @hvn.  The thing with `<pre>` is that it will come out in a terrible looking font.  If you want it to look nicer, use HTML tags.  As for the changing of the values on the lines, you didn't specify that AND, it's simply achieved by adding more `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 0):

> How to split email body text in logic app

I have reproduced in my environment and below are expected results:

You can simply use **`<pre>`** tag as below:

**`Design:`**

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image: https://i.imgur.com/49ebt1J.png]

[image]

**`Codeview:`**

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "<pre>\nHello Customer,\n\nThanks for reaching out to us. We appreciate your interest in our business. This is to confirm that we’ve successfully received your request you need immediate assistance or have any further questions, feel free to call us at phone.\n\nBest Regards, Support Team\n</pre>",
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Send_an_email_(V2)": {
                "inputs": {
                    "body": {
                        "Body": "<p>@{outputs('Compose')}</p>",
                        "Importance": "Normal",
                        "Subject": "IMPORTANT",
                        "To": "v-rbojja@microsoft.com"
                    },
                    "host": {
                        "connection": {
                            "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                        }
                    },
                    "method": "post",
                    "path": "/v2/Mail"
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "ApiConnection"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "defaultValue": {},
                "type": "Object"
            }
        },
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {
                    "schema": {}
                },
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/resourceGroups/rbojja/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365",
                    "id": "/subscriptions/b83c1ed3/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus/managedApis/office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```